# Pandas dataframe Grouping and Counting with validations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I am currently making an analysis to perform the following:

**1.  I need to calculate whether 4 entries per year exists for 'No. People' for 2018 and 2019. Same dates one should be excluded (does
    not matter which one)**

It should look like the following:

```
Year    Gender  No. People 
18      Men         11
        Woman        8
        Not Applied  3
19      Men         14
        Woman        5
        Not Applied  0
```

The No. People column shows the count of No. People.

**2. Check per Gender whether the last 10 months in a 10-day period more than 6 entries in No. People exists.**

Result could look like:

```
Period                   Gender      Entries
01/23/2019 - 01/15/2019  Men         6
N/A                      Woman       N/A
N/A                      Not Applied N/A
```

**3. Check whether there are 11 measures for No. People over the last 3 month**

```
Period                   Gender      Entries
12/20/2018 - 01/23/2019  Men         26
12/20/2018 - 01/23/2019  Woman       13
12/20/2018 - 12/26/2018  Not Applied N/A
```

Somehow it look complictaed and thats why I struggle with the code.

I started to use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'path'
filename = 'excel.xls'
final_path = path + '/' + filename
ws_name = 'Sheet1'

df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)['No. People'].agg(['count'])
```

but somhow I am struggeling with the results or errors.

The data looks like the following which is in Excel:

```
Date    Gender  No. People
12/20/18    Men 4
12/21/18    Men 9
12/22/18    Men 3
12/23/18    Men 9
12/24/18    Men 6
12/25/18    Men 1
12/26/18    Men 3
12/27/18    Men 8
12/28/18    Men 3
12/29/18    Men 5
12/30/18    Men 8
12/31/18    Men 
01/01/19    Men 
01/02/19    Men 
01/03/19    Men 
01/04/19    Men 9
01/05/19    Men 7
01/06/19    Men 5
01/07/19    Men 1
01/08/19    Men 8
01/09/19    Men 5
01/10/19    Men 6
01/11/19    Men 9
01/12/19    Men 7
01/13/19    Men 
01/14/19    Men 
01/15/19    Men 
01/16/19    Men 
01/17/19    Men 
01/18/19    Men 
01/19/19    Men 6
01/20/19    Men 5
01/21/19    Men 2
01/22/19    Men 5
01/23/19    Men 1
12/20/18    Women   6
12/21/18    Women   6
12/22/18    Women   2
12/23/18    Women   2
12/24/18    Women   2
12/25/18    Women   
12/26/18    Women   
12/27/18    Women   
12/28/18    Women   1
12/29/18    Women   1
12/30/18    Women   4
12/31/18    Women   
01/01/19    Women   
01/02/19    Women   
01/03/19    Women   
01/04/19    Women   
01/05/19    Women   
01/06/19    Women   
01/07/19    Women   
01/08/19    Women   
01/09/19    Women   
01/10/19    Women   
01/11/19    Women   
01/12/19    Women   
01/13/19    Women   
01/14/19    Women   
01/15/19    Women   
01/16/19    Women   
01/17/19    Women   
01/18/19    Women   
01/19/19    Women   4
01/20/19    Women   6
01/21/19    Women   8
01/22/19    Women   9
01/23/19    Women   4
12/20/18    Not Applied 6
12/21/18    Not Applied 2
12/22/18    Not Applied 3
12/23/18    Not Applied 
12/24/18    Not Applied 
12/25/18    Not Applied 
12/26/18    Not Applied
```

Comment: Could you show exacly what code you tried? The one you added is not complete, like what is the RPO column you are calling? what errors are you getting? where are you stuck?

Comment: @effy sorry my mistake. I corrected the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, it is good just add grouping by gender too

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year, 'Gender'])['No. People'].agg(['count'])
```

For second to group it by periods of 10 days you can use pandas Grouper class

```
df.sort_values(by=['Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
from_date = df.iloc[0]['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=10)
last_10_months = df[df.Date >= from_date]
count_people = last_10_months.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='10D'), 'Gender']).count()
count_people[count_people['No. People'] > 6]
```

same for third with the month

```
df.sort_values(by=['Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
from_date = df.iloc[0]['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3)
last_3_months = df[df.Date >= from_date]
df.groupby(['Gender']).count()
count_people[count_people['No. People'] > 11]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Two more questions. Is it possible to perform for the second one a grouping for 10 months like 10 months buckets and shor the results as you defined it?  And for the thrid one group it in 3 month buckets?

Comment: you mean group it by 10 months and then by 10 days? try `df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='10M'), pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='10D'), 'Gender']).count()`

Comment: That is what I was looking for.i only hvae more question. Can I restrict the `df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='10M'), pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='10D'), 'Gender']).count()` also that I really just look into the last 10M nothing further? I mean lets say 01.01.2019 minus 10 month I would only look into the period until 1. März 2018 and not further. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes so for example, after sorting to get the last date: `df.sort_values(by=['Date'], ascending=False)
from_date = df.iloc[0]['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=10)
df[df.Date > from_date]`

Comment: Thanks it is close, I meant more that in the alst 10M in a 10-day period I should have more than 6 entries in the No. of people

Comment: to check if the no of people is greater than 6 you can filter your dataframe, I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is so great... You made my day